# Why is my file reading via fstream::read slow on another computer with similar hardware?

Tags: c++

Assuming the following code:

```cpp
constexpr int nBufferSize = 1024 * 1024;
auto aBuffer = std::make_unique<char[]>(nBufferSize);
std::ifstream pInput(pFile, std::ios::binary | std::ios::in);

while(pInput)
{
    pInput.read(&aBuffer[0], nBufferSize);
}
```

On my desktop computer, this entire task takes 1400ms to complete on the first run, then 1100ms on the second run. The file size is 1.8GB and I'm reading through an M.2 SSD.

When I run it through my HDD, the task takes 9000ms~ to complete. Which makes sense, hard drives are slower.

However, on my colleague's machine that runs an M.2 SSD (although of a different brand), the task takes 12000ms to complete, which is even slower than my HDD.

Our CPUs and RAM speeds are similar (R7 3700x here, R5 3600x on their machine. 3200MHz RAM on both machines). Both of the operating systems are the latest versions of Windows 10. They ran system health checks to ensure that the hardware isn't faulty, and it seems fine. Other programs, disk benchmarking software included, do not seem to be affected by any kind of slowness and our speeds are almost identical there.

Comment: Similar amounts of RAM? Lots of RAM available? How many times did you run the test? When you read a large file, it should be placed in the page cache. The next time you read it (even in a new process), it should be much faster and not depend on the storage medium.

Comment: Do you compile both times on release?

Comment: @ALX23z yes, it's the same executable

Comment: @MikelRychliski same amounts of RAM, 32GB. I'll see with my colleague if Claytorpedo's answer regarding antivirus interference is correct

Comment: Side note: using a `std::ifstream` implies `std::ios::in`. You don't have to add it.

Comment: No idea if this is related to your problem but as far as I know an SSD without a DRAM cache can be slower than a HDD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be a lot of things: amount of RAM, how many programs and services are running, health of the drive, how full the drive is, etc.

The first thing I'd check for is antivirus interference, which if you've sent your colleague an exe is probably scanning everything you're writing.